# How to include PATH executable in visual studio post-build

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to run a web app build process from Visual Studio and I got trouble running my scripts as the executable from the PATH config aren't included in the runned scripts.

Is there a way I can make sure the script is executed in a normal command line process? Or is there a way I can load these executable so they're available in the post/pre build script?

I'm using ruby and node.js in the build process (managed via Grunt). I can get Grunt to run easily by specifying the full absolute path, but then it fails when it tries to access Ruby commands.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution working for me, I just launch the command in the cmd.exe process like so:

```
start cmd /C myCommand
```

With grunt, the full command can be this if someone is wondering:

```
start cmd /C %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd release --no-color > grunt_output.txt
```